# Receiving email in Node.js

Tags: email, smtp, node.js, pop3

I see a lot of Node.js modules out there that sends mail through SMTP.

But is there a module to receive mail?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are looking for an e-mail client library. Currently, there are 2 options (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules)):

- [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) (IMAP)
- [n3](https://github.com/andris9/n3) (POP3, experimental)

I never used them before, but usage is pretty straight forward (according to the docs). **node-imap** seems to be the more stable library and it has been tested against gmail. If IMAP is an option in your environment, i'd stick with **node-imap**.

Comment: @schaermu, @foobar, I have tried https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap, It works perfectly but we need to enable `LESS SECURE APP` from our Gmail account (for security reasons). I want to meet the security criteria of Gmail. But from where I can get the checklist? What should be the flow (Client side and Server side) in order to access the Gmail inbox without enabling `LESS SECURE APP`, using this node module? Thanks.

Answer (score 38):

The [Mailin](https://github.com/Flolagale/mailin) module allows you to receive emails, parse them and post them to a webhook of your choice. It is based on [simplesmtp](https://github.com/andris9/simplesmtp). It also checks the dkim and spf, computes a spamassassin score and determines the message language.

Even if it does not fit your needs exactly, you can have a look at the code, it might help you.
(Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of [Mailin](https://github.com/Flolagale/mailin))

Comment: Can mailin listen to emails of a gmail account ? and notifies when an email has arrived. sort of like https://github.com/jcreigno/nodejs-mail-notifier

Answer (score 10):

If you want the actual server in node.js check out

- https://github.com/ralphholzmann/node-smtp/blob/master/smtp.js
- https://github.com/riegel/node.js-SMTP-server
- https://github.com/aredridel/node-smtp/

Comment: but arent those links to servers that implement the SMTP protocol?

Comment: @GrantGryczan SMTP is for both receiving and sending mail. The first link provided by Drew is literally exactly what I needed, based on the OP's question.

Answer (score 8):

The solution that I found is [mail-listener2](https://github.com/chirag04/mail-listener2). I was able to get up and running with this in just a few minutes, it ties in [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) and [mailparser](https://github.com/andris9/mailparser) nicely out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following library if you don't need to work with IMAP and emails hosted elsewhere:
https://github.com/proxied-mail/proxiedmail-js-client

Simply if you're able to put your MX or use another domain from yours it's the best solution that allows creating emails and then sending you a webhook or showing you emails through Rest API.